# the word "array" being returned? sql for wordpress returning an array when its not an array... I hope

Tags: php

I am creating the first of many sql statements to interact with a custom built database in wordpress and am falling at the first hurdle! To test that the php is working, I am entering a simple (I thought) statement and the result I am getting is `[Array]` but it should be returning a `string` (the `username`).

I see that some other posts say that I should be using `print_r` but the answer should not be an array. I have checked the syntax through phpmyadmin and it returns a name - as I believe it should..

```
<?php


global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT user_login FROM wpvh_users WHERE id = 2');
echo $results;

?>
```

all help really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The function `get_results` returns an array, containing one entry.
Therefore you have to select the first element of that entry and display it :

```
echo $results[0]['user_login'];
```

Comment: Many Thanks for the help Jesus - really appreciated. Unfortunately though, it now returns nothing? No idea why....

Comment: If you do `var_dump($results)` you will see the entire structure of your variable. Can you try that and show us the result ?